# How to allow Rundeck job to pickup latest node inventory list?

Tags: rundeck

There are two Rundeck Jobs in the infra:

Job 01: (For local execution)

1. Will allow the user to upload a file consisting of servers list (Nodes: Execute Locally on rundeck)
2. The new nodes list will get updated to the new inventory file (resources.xml) which will be used by Rundeck henceforth
3. Triggers an API call to run Job 02

Job 02: (For remote execution)

1. Will run the Job for the updated inventory list.

Result: The runs were successful. The new nodes are reflecting to the latest inventory.

Problem: The issue is after 5 such executions, Rundeck uses the cache inventory names. For example, For Job execution #5, it uses #4 execution's inventory list. Is there any way this can be avoided? This could turn out to be a bigger issue when deployed in large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decrease the model source cache delay time, go to Project Settings > Edit Nodes > Configuration tab, and set the Cache Delay textbox in seconds (default value: 30 seconds).

Comment: Thanks @MegaDrive68k! But this did not resolve the issue yet.
What have done is, reduced the Cache Delay textbox to 15 (15 seconds). And have added a sleep condition of 30s before triggering the job through API call. So that, this new job will get atleast 30s time to reflect on the latest updated node inventory